# Identity certificate import after deleting CSR from ASA

Tags: cisco-asa

I generated a CSR using CLI, then Thawte senT me certificate. I typed some commands, something went wrong, and I deleted the CSR from the ASA.

Do I have to generate new a CSR and ask Thawte for new certificate, or is it possible to restore a deleted CSR? I have ASDM access as well.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will have used the command:

```
crypto ca enroll TP-NAME
```

where TP-NAME is the name of your trustpoint.

All you will need to do now is:

```
crypto ca import TP-NAME certificate
```

where TP-NAME is the same as the one you used for creating the CSR (using the enroll command)

Answer (score 0):

I install certificates so infrequently that I do this all the time and I never bother trying to restore it.

It's trivial to just re-do the CSR and request another cert. Most SSL cert providers will give you unlimited re-keys and even if its an EV certificate they'll re-issue the certificate within minutes.

You'll probably save a lot of time by just starting from the beginning.